# Linear Transformation with the Change of Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inverse, coordinate-systems

Let A′
A
′
 denote the standard (coordinate) basis in ℝn
R
n
 and suppose that T:ℝn→ℝn
T
:
R
n
→
R
n
 is a linear transformation with matrix A
A
 so that T(x)=Ax
. Further, suppose that A
 is invertible. Let B
 be another (non-standard) basis for ℝn
R
n
, and denote by A(B)
A
(
B
)
 the matrix for T
 with respect to B
.

a) Prove that
A
(
B
)
 is also an invertible matrix.

b) If {x1,…,xk} is a linearly independent set in ℝn
, prove that
{
A
(
B
)
[
x
1
]
(
B
)
…
A
(
B
)
[
x
k
]
(
B
)
}
is also linearly independent, where x
 denotes the B
-coordinate vector of x.

Ok I think I understand now that A_B = P(A_E)P^-1, where P is the change of coordinates matrix. And since A_E is invertible (it says so in the problem) and obviously P is invertible, then the product PAP^-1 gives an invertible matrix? Am I close here? And how is the second set also linearly independent? I'm lost here.

Comment: Use LaTeX and MathJax for formatting: click on "Help", go to the Help Center and read the answer to the first question under "Our model", entitled "How can I format mathematics here?". It contains a couple of links that should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

a) Yes you are almost there. Use the fact that $A_E$ and $P$ are invertible to explicitly write down an inverse for $PA_E P^{-1}$.

b) Suppose otherwise, that the set of $A x_i$ is not linearly independent. Then write down what that means as an equation, and multiply by invertible matrices to show that the $x_i$ are not linearly independent, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Would P be from Standard to B coordinates and P^-1 be from B coordinates to standard coordinates? And would the inverse for PAP^-1 just be P^-1AP? I'm not sure how to inverse a product of three matrices

Comment: If $v$ is in $B$ coordinates and the columns of $P$ are the basis elements of $B$, then $Pv$ converts it to standard coordinates. The inverse of $PAP^{-1}$ is $PA^{-1} P^{-1}$; to see this, just multiply them together and see what happens.

Comment: so P is from B to Standard, and P^-1 is from standard back to B coordinates?

Comment: And for part (b), I assume the the set {x1,...,xk} is linearly dependent then apply A and that is also linearly dependent, then there are c1A(x1)...ckA(xk)=0 where c1-ck are not all 0, but what "invertible matrices" am I multiplying by here? PAP^-1?

Comment: Ok so far I have that if we suppose that {x1....xk} is linearly dependent, there exists c1...ck not all = o such that c1A(x1)....ckA(xk)=0 since T is a linear transformation. How do I get from that equation to the one in b coordinates? Do I multiply each A on the left by P and on the right by P^-1 to get A_B for each one? but what about the x's?